# How to make button from a button

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a question about the project that I'm working on. Basically, I've got a couple of raspberry pis and I made one of them to control the rest with a simple webpage. On the home page, there are two buttons: the two controlled pis, with information about them (name of device and IP address). On the same page, I've got a third button which I made like a plus sign. When I press it, I want to create new buttons for new devices. I want to be able to type in the name and the IP address. In addition, when you press the devices buttons, they redirect you to the control page of the certain device.

The problem is that I looked around the internet for that problem but I can't find anything close to what I want.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! As you have posed your query, it is much too broad. Please describe the technologies you are using (Angular, Vue, PHP, Python, JavaScript, TypeScript, etc) and provide a short example of something you tried but isn't working.

Comment: Hello. I’m using Apache as a web server and in the website i’m using mainly php. I haven’t tried anything because I can’t think of a way to do it. I just wanted to check if it’s even possible and with what language.